# Dataflow load a table from GBQ, transform and load back to BGQ

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

We tried to load a table from GBQ, do transformations and move back to GBQ. But it is giving me an error
as
`Workflow failed. Causes: S01:Read data from BQ+Preprocess data+Write data to BQ/Write/NativeWrite failed., BigQuery import job Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0, error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Start of array encountered without start of object.`

Code as below:

```
query = ('SELECT * FROM `<project>.<Dataset>.<table>` limit 100')
bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)
table_schema = "Col1:INTEGER,col2:INTEGER,col3:INTEGER"
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
(p
     | "Read data from BQ" >> beam.io.Read(bq_source)
     | "Preprocess data" >> beam.ParDo(transferinput(project=<project_id>, bucket_name=<bucket>)) 
     #| 'Write to Cloud Storage' >> beam.io.WriteToText(bucket>+ '/output_rec.txt')
     |"Write data to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=<table_name_new>, dataset=<Dataset>, project=<project_id>,schema=table_schema,                                     create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,                                              write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
     )

class transferinput(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self,project=None, bucket_name='bucket_name'): 
        self._project = project
        self._bucket_name = bucket_name  
     
    def process(self, element):
        """ Format the input to the desired shape"""
        df = pd.DataFrame([element], columns=element.keys())        
        df[features] = df[features].fillna('-1', )  
        output = df[features]
        output = output.to_dict('records')
        return [output]
```

Is the return format an issue?

Comment: Looks like the you just want to return `output` because to_dict('records') return a list

Comment: Even just output failed.. I believe it tried to convert JSON.. I tried JSON also.. and it failed

Comment: Hm, I was able to run your code when I made that change. The only part missing was "features", but I assume you're just selecting a set of columns from df. Maybe features doesn't match table_schema?

Comment: I was able to move the data to Storage if I uncomment the "Write to Cloud Storage" piece it works without any issue

Comment: Got it, I thought you tried to write both to storage and BQ, as that won't work the way this pipeline is structured. 1) What happens when you don't specify table_schema? 2) Does the BigQuery table have matching schemas?

Comment: would you try logging (`logging.info(output)`) some of the records in the process method and see what they look like?